# (Sanity Check) Prisoner's Escape Probability

Tags: probability-theory

This is a variation of the prisoner's escape problem from Ross; do my solutions seem correct?

A prisoner is trapped in a cell with three doors. The first door leads to freedom after 1 day of travel. The second door leads to a tunnel that returns him to his cell after 4 days of travel. The third door leads back to the cell after 2 days.

a) Assuming that the prisoner will always select doors 1, 2, and 3 with probabilities 0.2, 0.3, and 0.5 respectively, what is the expected number of days until he reaches freedom?

b) What is the variance of the number of days until the prisoner is free?

**Solution for part (a):**

Let X denote the number of days and let Y denote the door selected.
 $$E[X]=E[E[X│Y]]$$
 $$=E[X│Y=1]P(Y=1)+[X│Y=2]P(Y=2)+[X│Y=3]P(Y=3)$$
 $$=(1)(0.20)+(4+E[X])(0.30)+(2+E[X])(0.50)$$
 $$=(.20)+(1.20)+(.30)E[X]+1+(.50)E[X]$$
 $$=2.40+(.80)E[X]$$

$$(.20)E[X]=2.40$$
 $$E[X]=12 days$$

**Solution for part (b):**
To find the variance, we note that $Var(X)=E[X^{2}]-(E[X]){^2}$

$$E[X^{2}]=(1)(0.20)+(4+E[X])^{2} (0.30)+(2+E[X])^{2}(0.50)$$
 $$=(0.20)+(16+8E[X]+E[X^{2}])(0.30)+(4+4E[X]+E[X^{2}])(0.50)$$
 $$=(0.20)+4.8+2.4E[X]+(0.30)E[X^{2}]+2+2E[X]+(0.50)E[X^{2}]$$
 $$=7+4.4E[X]+(0.80)E[X^{2}]$$

$$(0.20)E[X^{2}]=7+4.4E[X]$$
  $$E[X^{2}]=551.78$$

Then $Var(X)=E[X^{2}]-(E[X])^{2}=551.78-12^{2} =407.78$

Comment: Looks fine to me!