# Variance if expectation is previously found using conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

***The question:***

"An explorer has lost his way and is trapped in a cave deep underground. There are 3 tunnels he can follow – the first tunnel leads to the surface after 1 day, the second leads back to the same cave in 4 days, and the third tunnel leads back to the cave in 2 days. Suppose the explorer will always select the first, second and third tunnel with probabilities 0.2, 0.3 and 0.5. Compute the expectation and the variance of the number of days until the explorer is free."

Okay, so I successfully found the expectation using the conditioned expectation formula E[X]=E[E[X/Y]]=the sum of E[X/Y=y]*P{Y=y}. It was not difficult reaching to an equation format and then from there extracting E[X].

I am going through hell trying to find the variance, but it seems I'm at an impasse. All hints or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you guys.

PS: Sorry for the amateurish formatting. New here.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547810/sanity-check-prisoners-escape-probability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brute force method, using pmf
$$f(n_2,n_3)=p_1p_2^{n_2}p_3^{n_3}{n_2+n_3\choose n_2}$$
then
$$E[D]=\sum_{n_2=0}^\infty\sum_{n_3=0}^\infty(1+4n_2+2n_3)f(n_2,n_3)$$
and
$$E[D^2]=\sum_{n_2=0}^\infty\sum_{n_3=0}^\infty(1+4n_2+2n_3)^2f(n_2,n_3)$$
Using $p_1=0.2, p_2=0.3, p_3=0.5$, WolframAlpha gives $E[D]=12$ and $E[D^2]=299$, so
$$V[D]=E[D^2]-E[D]^2=155$$

Comment: I definitely understand the mechanism you've employed. I just couldn't come up with the probability mass function myself. Do you mind briefly elaborating how you derived that formula? Thank you! 

Also, I saw this solution somewhere else. My original attempts revolved around this way of thinking, but I just quit altogether. 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547810/sanity-check-prisoners-escape-probability

Comment: The decisions are independent so the probability of two decisions is just the product of the probability of each one. The last decision is to take tunnel 1, so that is included as well. The final term is the number of orderings of the $n_2+n_3$ decisions that have $n_2$ decisions to take tunnel 2. You can check by summing the pmf over all $n_2$ and $n_3$ to get 1.

Answer (score 0):

Let the $x$ be the random variable of the total number of days to reach chanel $1$ for the first time (to get out of the cave) for an arbitrary path. Let $\mathbf 1_{t=k}$ be the characteristic function for the first step tunnel number $t$ taking on natural number $k$ and $d_k$ days.
$$
x^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n x^2\mathbf 1_k = \sum_{k=1}^n(x_k+d_k)^2\mathbf 1_{t=k} = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2\mathbf 1_{t=k} +2\sum_{k=1}^n d_kx_k\mathbf 1_{t=k} +\sum_{k=1}^n d_k^2\mathbf 1_{t=k},
$$
where $x_k=x-d_k$.

Take expectation of both sides of the equation,
\begin{align}
\mathbf E\left[x^2\right] &= \sum_{k=2}^n \mathbf E\big[x_k^2\big|t=k\big]p_k+2\sum_{k=2}^nd_k\mathbf E\big[x_k\big|t=k\big]p_k +\sum_{k=1}^nd_k^2p_k \\
&= \mathbf E\left[x^2\right]\sum_{k=2}^n p_k+2\mathbf E[x]\sum_{k=2}^nd_kp_k +\sum_{k=1}^nd_kp_k.
\end{align}
where the last line results from the independence of $x_k$ from the present state. Similar derivation leads to
$$\mathbf E[x] = \mathbf E[x]\sum_{k=2}^n p_k+\sum_{k=1}^nd_kp_k.$$
Simple arithmetics solves both $\mathbf E[x]$ and $\mathbf E\left[x^2\right]$ and thus the variance.